# What is quickest way to find hackers entrance to computer?

Tags: windows-10

I have a hacker in computer, what steps to remove, block entrance to computer programs.  I tried going to basics, reloading windows...I do not know what steps to take.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there might be some steps of interest.

If you're on Windows you can issue `openfiles` to check what files are opened in your computer by other computer users.

Turn on Firewall (`WF.msc`) and Window Defender (`sc start windefend`) if they're disabled.

Unshare all the shares through Shared Folder window (`fsmgmt.msc`).

Add a strong password and make user all the other users, especially the Administrator, have a secure password set through User Accounts window (`Netplwiz.exe`).

And so on on that example.